# No metadata for "TasksRepository" was found in NestJS typeORM postgres

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to simply create a repository for my entity and then use it in my service file for database action i am using postgres.

but i keep getting this error

```
[Nest] 32358 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "TasksRepository" was found.
```

Here is my code:

tasks.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TasksRepository } from './tasks.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TasksRepository])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService]
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

tasks.repository.ts:

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { Task } from "./tasks.entity";

@EntityRepository(Task)
export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {
    
}
```

tasks.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TaskStatus } from './tasks.enum';
import { CreateTaskDto } from 'src/dto/tasks/create-task.dto';
import { TasksRepository } from './tasks.repository';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Task } from './tasks.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TasksRepository)
        private tasksRepository: TasksRepository,
    ) {}

    async getTaskById(id: string): Promise<Task> {
        const task = await this.tasksRepository.findOne({where: {id}});
        if (!task) {
            throw new NotFoundException;
        }
        return task;
    }

    async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
        const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
        const task = this.tasksRepository.create({
            title,
            description,
            status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
        });

        await this.tasksRepository.save(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

tasks.controller.ts:

```
@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
    constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) {}

    @Get('/:id')
    getTaskById(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Task> { 
        return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
    }

    @Post()
    createTask(@Body() createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
        return this.tasksService.createTask(createTaskDto);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksModule } from './modules/tasks/tasks.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TasksModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      database: 'task-management',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

i keep getting 500 internal server error when trying to test out my endpoints from my controller

Comment: Can you show the config passed to `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` as well?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel i did, please check the edited question

Comment: What version of TypeORM are you using? The current `0.3.x` removed the `@EntityRepository()` approach

Comment: @JayMcDoniel 0.3.17 then what should i use instead of @EntityRepository()? because it is indeed telling me that it is deprecated

Comment: [Did you read their changelog](https://typeorm.io/changelog#030httpsgithubcomtypeormtypeormpull8616-2022-03-17)?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel no thanks for including it, but u could have helped me solve the issue and also refering me to the documentation. i solved it myself.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it this way. In typeorm 0.3.x the @EntityRepository() decorator is deprecated.

```
import { Repository, DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { Task } from "./tasks.entity";
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TaskStatus } from "./tasks.enum";
import { CreateTaskDto } from "src/dto/tasks/create-task.dto";

@Injectable()
export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
        super(Task, dataSource.createEntityManager());
      }

    async getTaskById(id: string) : Promise<Task> {
        const task = await this.findOne({where: {id}});
        if (!task) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Task not found');
        }
        return task;
    }  

    async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {

        const { title, description } = createTaskDto;

        const task = this.create({
            title,
            description,
            status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
        });

        await this.save(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

then the most important thing is you import the TasksRepository in the providers array in the tasks.module.ts and put the entity task in the `.forFeature` array

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService, TasksRepository] 
})
export class TasksModule {}
```